# sharing data between c++/c and Java

Tags: java, c, data-sharing

I am working with a c process that reads an ambient sensor via stream, each second it reads 1000 samples about light,Temperature and sound of the surrounding ambient, now I would like to read this data by means of a java program I know there are solutions such as share memory but I'm looking for some good tutorial, guide, example that can help me to achieve my task.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: @DavidPostill - there are just three technologies I can recommend as an answer. Do you know more?

Comment: @bobah Of course, check the list I've put up here: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp#introduction

Comment: @SamuelAudet - I was referring to the mainstream/prod-ready

Answer (score 0):

You can go plain [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface), or use one of [JACE](http://code.google.com/p/jace/wiki/Overview) or [JNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access), whichever suits best based depending on whether you want to call C++ code from Java or other way around. All three are well documented on the net.

Comment: Dear, thank you for your response, my doubts are related to synchronization between the two processes... to be clear, if it would be a pure-java with a sync queue it would be very easy to achieve but in this case i do not know...